# RDP Dynamic resolution: how to know the current resolution?

Tags: remote-desktop

The dynamic resolution feature updates the resolution of the RDP session based on the size of your RDP window.
So if enlarge the RDP window, the resolution is increased.
Now the problem is, how do I know what the exact resolution is after it has been dynamically updated?

It seems the command `wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription` will only show the resolution of the physical monitor, not the rdp session.

Comment: Given the resolution is dynamic and changes as needed, why do you need to know the exact resolution?  Question of curiosity.

Comment: @John for example, when an application is misbehaving inside an RDP session, and it is suspected that the issue has something to do with resolution. It would be good to know what exactly the resolution is when the issue happens.  Other than that, I just thought this should be something *knowable*.  It's quite strange that something seemingly easy is just so hard or even impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can find out the screen resolution of an RDP session by using the snipping tool inside of the rdp session to capture the entire screen, then examining the dimension of the resulting image.
Because the snipping tool is running inside of the rdp session, it does not know it is inside of an rdp session and is not affected by zooming etc.